# Cannot install RMagick 2.15.4

Tags: ruby, rhel, rmagick

I'm trying to install RMagick 2.15.4 on RHEL 6.7 using Ruby 2.0.0 and ImageMagick 7.0.2.
I've installed ImageMagick7, ImageMagick7-c++, ImageMagick7-c++-devel, ImageMagick7-devel, ImageMagick7-libs packages, made a symlinks:

```
ln -s /usr/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickCore/ /usr/include/ImageMagick-7/magick
ln -s /usr/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/ /usr/include/ImageMagick-7/wand
```

And launched install:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/ImageMagick-7/ gem install rmagick
```

But got this errors:

```
======================================================================
Thu 16Jun16 05:08:41
This installation of RMagick 2.15.4 is configured for
Ruby 2.0.0 (x86_64-linux) and ImageMagick 7.0.2
======================================================================


Configured compile options: {:magick_config=>false, :pkg_config=>true, :magick_version=>"7.0.2", :local_libs=>" -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI  ", :cflags=>" -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-7  ", :cppflags=>" -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-7  ", :ldflags=>" -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI  ", :defs=>[], :config_h=>"Makefile rmagick.h"}

make "DESTDIR="
compiling rmmontage.c
In file included from rmmontage.c:14:
rmagick.h:1210: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MagickPixelPacket’
rmagick.h:1219: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
rmagick.h:1224: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
rmagick.h:1240: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
rmagick.h:1253: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
rmagick.h:1289: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MagickPixelPacket’
rmmontage.c: In function ‘Montage_background_color_eq’:
rmmontage.c:110: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Color_to_PixelPacket’ from incompatible pointer type
rmagick.h:1209: note: expected ‘struct PixelPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PixelInfo *’
rmmontage.c: In function ‘Montage_border_color_eq’:
rmmontage.c:131: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Color_to_PixelPacket’ from incompatible pointer type
rmagick.h:1209: note: expected ‘struct PixelPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PixelInfo *’
rmmontage.c: In function ‘Montage_fill_eq’:
rmmontage.c:215: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Color_to_PixelPacket’ from incompatible pointer type
rmagick.h:1209: note: expected ‘struct PixelPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PixelInfo *’
rmmontage.c: In function ‘Montage_matte_color_eq’:
rmmontage.c:353: error: ‘MontageInfo’ has no member named ‘matte_color’
rmmontage.c: In function ‘Montage_stroke_eq’:
rmmontage.c:416: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Color_to_PixelPacket’ from incompatible pointer type
rmagick.h:1209: note: expected ‘struct PixelPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct PixelInfo *’
make: *** [rmmontage.o] Error 1
```

I checked all developer dependencies on https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.15.4, and they was satisfied.
How to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: What `yum search ImageMagick | grep -i wand` returns?

Comment: `php-magickwand.x86_64 : PHP API for ImageMagick
php54-php-magickwand.x86_64 : PHP API for ImageMagick
php55-php-magickwand.x86_64 : PHP API for ImageMagick
php56-php-magickwand.x86_64 : PHP API for ImageMagick
`

Comment: Installed php-magickwand - nothing changes.

Comment: It seems that `rmagick` works only with versions `>= 6.4.9` and `<= 6.9.7`. Checked with `rmagick 2.16.0`.